# Converting uint to Color

Tags: c#, winforms, colors

How can I convert an `uint` value to an ARGB `System.Drawing.Color`? I haven't found this on the internet yet...

I have just found methods for ARGB to `uint`.

My `uint` value came from:

```
uint aeroColor;
Dwmapi.DwmGetColorizationColor( out aeroColor, out opaque );
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

What does the `uint` represent? In general, you can use this:

```
Color c = Color.FromArgb(intvalue);
```

Using the [appropriate overload](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/2zys7833.aspx). However, this expects an `int`, not a `uint`. If you have a `uint` with the same memory layout (as in your case) then the following should work:

```
uint aeroColor;
Dwmapi.DwmGetColorizationColor(out aeroColor, out opaque);
Color c = Color.FromArgb((int) aeroColor);
```

Comment: why not? then what type of variable returns it?

Comment: @Victor Ah, I see. You can probably just cast the result since the format is the same (0xAARRGGBB).